# Simple Color Fade on Border

Tags: css

not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm trying to fade the border of a div from 1 color to the next on hover.. here is what I have

```
.box {
background: #212121;
border: 1px solid #464646;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #212121;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #212121;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #212121;
-moz-transition-property: all;
-webkit-transition-property: all;
-o-transition-property: all;
transition-property: all;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover{
border: 1px solid #f72c73;
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Works fine in latest firefox beta. What browser are you using? Also, show how you try to use it perhaps?

Comment: @joe Boddy Works Perfect Check  to now http://jsfiddle.net/rmPaZ/

Comment: Post your HTML may you are doing wrong in HTML